# Wordpress: display the video of a post_format Video

Tags: php, wordpress, post-format

I've a post with `post_format = video`, in which the content are a video and a text (in the default editor). I need to display the video and the text **separately**. How can do it?

For now, I've this code:

```
  global $post;
  $tmp_post = $post;
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-video' ) // post format
        )
    )
  );
  $video_posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ($video_posts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata( $post );
    echo get_the_title($post->ID);
    // ------> Here what code for get the video?
    // html
    // ...
    // ...    
    // ------> Here what code for get the text (if possible)?
  endforeach;
  $post = $tmp_post;
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end I found a solution myself: I made a function that return the `iframe` for the first video inside the post with id `$post_id`:

```
function get_first_video_embed($post_id) {
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));
  $iframes = get_media_embedded_in_content( $content, 'iframe' );
  return $video_post_iframe = $iframes[0];
}
```